# Flutter build fail with unknown property 'runtimeConfiguration' error

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

when i try to build apk from my current application i get this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Initialization script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\aar_init_script.gradle'
>     line: 122
> - What went wrong: Could not get unknown property 'runtimeConfiguration' for object of type
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.LibraryVariantImpl.

and i'm not sure whats that and how can i resolve

**gradle-wrapper.properties:**

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

**build.gradle:**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
```